# Py_BuildValue: make tuple with bool?

Tags: python, python-extensions

I see in [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p2/ext/buildValue.html), that I can build tuple value with int (specifying 'i'). I need to make tuple with bool, e.g. `(True, 10)`. How can I make such tuple with bool (what specifier needed)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no predefined format character for that conversion, but it is trivial to simulate one by inserting `Py_True` or `Py_False` object into the tuple, as appropriate. For example:

```
int i = ...;
bool b = ...;
PyObject *tuple_with_bool = Py_BuildValue("Oi", b ? Py_True: Py_False, i);
```

Another option is to use [PyBool_FromLong](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/bool.html?highlight=fromlong#c.PyBool_FromLong) to do the conversion. In that case, remember to use the `N` format to account for `PyBool_FromLong` returning a new reference:

```
PyObject *tuple_with_bool = Py_BuildValue("Ni", PyBool_FromLong(b), i);
```

Comment: Weird nickname, but helped. Tks.

Comment: The `Py_RETURN_FALSE` and `Py_RETURN_TRUE` macros are helpful too (they increment the refcount for you): https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bool.html